# django inline widget template script not rendering on add another inline

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-admin, inline

When I add another inline the template have some javascript code...

the code is here : https://github.com/jeremyjbowers/django-autocomplete/blob/master/autocomplete/templates/admin/autocomplete/inline_widget.html

when the user press on the add another inline link on the admin page, the other inline is added but the script tag doesnt apper, in the previous ones created before it work ok.

I'm using https://github.com/jeremyjbowers/django-autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

This is because rendering *inline javascript in widgets is a poor practice*.

Even if the script tag was added, I don't think that the `$(document).ready` callback would ever be triggered.

If you want to fix it, you can see how [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/commit/cc5eacc3004b90535449b87c6ec81e4640d3d979) does this:

1. Instead of initializing the widget on document load, do it [in a **custom signal callback**](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/commit/cc5eacc3004b90535449b87c6ec81e4640d3d979#L0L32),
2. Emit that custom signal **[on document load](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/commit/cc5eacc3004b90535449b87c6ec81e4640d3d979#L1R320)**,
3. Emit that custom signal **[when a widget is created](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/commit/cc5eacc3004b90535449b87c6ec81e4640d3d979#L1R326)**.